# How to publish expo app without using expo xde

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

How can I publish expo app without using expo xde? I want to send the link to my friends. Is there any command that can do that?

Comment: To publish , you need expo xde only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the XDE for this, and it's very straight-forward.  If you have not already done so, you will need to install the `exp` command-line client first.

```
npm install -g exp
```

You may also need to log in first.

```
exp login
```

Then there are essentially two steps.

### Step 1 - Configure `app.json`

You will first of all need to configure the variables in your `app.json` file correctly - with the name, version and icon for your app, etc.. The method for this is explained [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html) (section 'Configure app.json').

### Step 2 - Publish

Then publish it as follows.

```
exp publish
```

Once all this is done a page for your project will be created at https://expo.io/@you/project-name - with a QR code that your friends can scan.

**Expo documentation**: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/exp-cli.html

Comment: If you want the apk for the store you need `exp build:android`